# How to reset values in ng-select in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select on a modal.

```html
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<ng-select #select name="currenies" [allowClear]="true" [items]="currencyList" [disabled]="disabled" (selected)="selected($event)" 
                        placeholder="Currency description + ISO code">
 </ng-select>

 </div>
</div>
```

After I close the modal, selected value attached to html remains constant. 
How to reset the ng-select?

Comment: I'm confused if this is for `angular` or `angularJs`.

Comment: this is angular not angularjs

Comment: Can you create a plunker. I'll help you fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

u can reset it using the method `clear` when the modal is closed :

```
 <div class="modal-body" (onClose)="select.clear()">
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use this

```
$('#modal_id').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this).find("select").val('').end();
})
```